# Wrapping labels in StreamGraph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to wrap labels whose width is greater than 10px. To achieve this I used Bostock's [wrap function](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321):

I used the `wrap` function in my code and called it by passing labels, for example "titanic eva mission impossible". However,the labels overlap with each other instead of each word coming in separated lines.

My project is here: [StreamGraph With AreaLabel](https://codepen.io/vchouksey/project/editor/XwKbMe)

```
<!doctype html>              

<html>    
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.8/d3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-area-label@1.2.0"></script>

<style>
  body {
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .area-label {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    height: 20;
    width: auto;
    fill-opacity: 0.7;
    fill: white;
  }
  path:hover {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    fill:black;
  }
  path {
    fill-opacity: 0.8;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
  }
  text {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="viz">
  <svg style="width:960px;height:500px;" ></svg>

</div>

<script>

  d3.csv("movies.csv", dataViz);

  function dataViz(data) 
{
    var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 960]);
    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([500, 0]);

    var movies = ["titanic eva mission impossible", "avatar", "akira", "frozen", "deliverance", "avengers"];

    var fillScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(movies)
      .range(["#fcd88a", "#cf7c1c", "#93c464", "#75734F", "#5eafc6", "#41a368"]);

    stacked = d3.stack()
                .offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
                .order(d3.stackOrderInsideOut)
                .keys(movies);

    yScale.domain([-50, 50]);

    var xValue = function (d) { return d.day; };

    var stackArea = d3.area()
      .x(d => xScale(xValue(d.data)))
      .y0(d => yScale(d[0]))
      .y1(d => yScale(d[1]))
      .curve(d3.curveBasis);

    d3.select("svg")
        .selectAll("path").data(stacked(data)).enter().append("path")
        .style("fill", d => fillScale(d.key))
        .attr("d", d => stackArea(d));

    labels = d3.select("svg")
               .selectAll('text').data(stacked(data))
    labels
    .enter().append("g")
    .append('text')
    .attr('class', 'area-label')
    .text(d => d.key)
    .attr('transform',
      d3.areaLabel(stackArea).interpolateResolution(1000).interpolate(true));

    d3.select("svg").select("g").select("text").call(wrap,10);
}
    function wrap(text, width) 
    {
      text.each(function() {
        var text = d3.select(this),
            words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
            word,
            line = [],
            lineNumber = 0,
            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
            y = text.attr("y"),
            dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
            tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
        while (word = words.pop()) {
          line.push(word);
          tspan.text(line.join(" "));
          if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
            line.pop();
            tspan.text(line.join(" "));
            line = [word];
            tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
          }
        }
      });
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `y` and `dy` attributes:

```
labels.enter().append("g")
    .append('text')
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    //etc...
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var movies = `day,titanic eva mission impossible,avatar,akira,frozen,deliverance,avengers
1,40,8,10,0,0,0
2,18,5,1,13,0,0
3,14,3,1,10,0,0
4,7,3,0,5,27,15
5,4,3,0,2,20,14
6,3,1,0,0,10,13
7,2,0,0,0,8,12
8,0,0,0,0,6,11
9,0,0,0,0,3,9
10,0,0,0,0,1,8`;

var data = d3.csvParse(movies);

dataViz(data);

function dataViz(data) {
  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 960]);
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 100]).range([500, 0]);

  var movies = ["titanic eva mission impossible", "avatar", "akira", "frozen", "deliverance", "avengers"];

  var fillScale = d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(movies)
    .range(["#fcd88a", "#cf7c1c", "#93c464", "#75734F", "#5eafc6", "#41a368"]);

  stacked = d3.stack()
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetSilhouette)
    .order(d3.stackOrderInsideOut)
    .keys(movies);

  yScale.domain([-50, 50]);

  var xValue = function(d) {
    return d.day;
  };

  var stackArea = d3.area()
    .x(d => xScale(xValue(d.data)))
    .y0(d => yScale(d[0]))
    .y1(d => yScale(d[1]))
    .curve(d3.curveBasis);

  d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("path").data(stacked(data)).enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", d => fillScale(d.key))
    .attr("d", d => stackArea(d));

  labels = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll('text').data(stacked(data))
  labels.enter().append("g")
    .append('text')
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr('class', 'area-label')
    .text(d => d.key)
    .attr('transform', d3.areaLabel(stackArea).interpolateResolution(1000).interpolate(true));

  d3.select("svg").select("g").select("text").call(wrap, 10);
}

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
      y = text.attr("y"),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
      tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

.area-label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 20;
  width: auto;
  fill-opacity: 0.7;
  fill: white;
}

path:hover {
  fill-opacity: 1;
  fill: black;
}

path {
  fill-opacity: 0.8;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
}

text {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.8/d3.min.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3-area-label@1.2.0"></script>
<div id="viz">
  <svg style="width:960px;height:500px;"></svg>
</div>
```

PS: d3-area-label positioned the text at the vertical center of the path. However, you'll have to move it up a bit, to avoid the text overlapping the path below.